# htaccess filesmatch(htm|html|php) except two specific files?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to automatically add the `X-Robots-Tag` header for all php, htm, html pages EXCEPT `/index.php` and `forgot.php`.

This would cover all of them:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

But how can I exclude `/index.php` and `/forgot.php` from that `FilesMatch` directive?

**What I want it to do :**

Valid for all .htm, .html, .php files

Exclude for `/index.(htm|html|php)`, `/forgot.(htm|html|php)`, but not `*/index.php` should be valid.

Hopefully that makes sense... I just want to exclude it from those two specific files at the base of the site.

**UPDATE:**
Playing around with this on [tester](https://regex101.com/), but still have some issues :

```
(?!.*/(index.php|forgot))(^.*\.(php|htm|html)$)
```

this is excluding URLs like `www.mysite.com/folder/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at this wrong the whole time.  Here is what I am using :

```
# BEGIN noindex,nofollow on all but login and forgot page
<IfModule mod_env.c>
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|forgot\.php)$ - [E=exclude:1]
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|html?)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=!exclude
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried? Have you tried something like this?

`<FilesMatch "^(^index|^forgot)\.(htm|html|php)$">`

Just want to point you in the right direction. I haven't tried this yet, but it's probably going to be a bit greedy and match files like `index_example.php` as well. Not just `index.php`.

These guys have an excellent reference on RegEx: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: This would seem to specifically match `index.php` and `forgot.php` - whereas the OP wants to _exclude_ these particular URLs. (?)